# Spark history-server stays empty

Tags: apache-spark

I set up spark alongside Hadoop with YARN as a resource manager. I set both `spark.history.fs.logDirectory` and `spark.eventLog.dir` to the same path in my hdfs file system. Also, `spark.eventLog.enabled` is set to `true` and I also checked history servers logs, but there are no errors (Only INFO). So I assume my problem isn't caused by permission errors. Also, I verified that application logs are actually created in the correct place, which is indeed the case. History servers logs also indicate that it is looking in the correct folder.

I don't have any idea why there are no application logs shown in the history server. Maybe I'm missing something fundamental.

Here are all important files (if that helps)

- Logs: https://pastebin.com/6TGE3NbQ
- spark-defaults.conf: https://pastebin.com/ZRv4JWbV
- ansible-playbook.yml: https://pastebin.com/dVqsGENk (Important lines: 166 - 192 and 370)

The ansible-playbook is used to set up the whole cluster.

Edit: The history server is even parsing files (see Logs) but it just refuses to display them.

Comment: I face same issue too with spark 3.3.2, it just stucks at Parsing eventLog. When I enable Debug or Trace level in log4j2, I can even see that Spark history server can check status and even get size of eventlog. But then nothing happens more. Can anyone help me please Thanks

Answer (score 2):

To have a proper History server setup, you need 3 things (also documented [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/monitoring.html#viewing-after-the-fact)):

- Your Spark applications need to write their logs to a certain directory. This can be done with the following configurations:

```
spark.eventLog.enabled true
spark.eventLog.dir someDirectory
```

- Your History Server needs to be running. This can be done like so:

```
./$SPARK_HOME/sbin/start-history-server.sh
```

- Your History Server needs to be looking at the correct directory to look at the logs. This can be configured like so:

```
spark.history.fs.logDirectory sameDirectoryAsTheOneAbove
```

So in your case, it seems like something is going wrong. There are a few things you can verify:

- **Are your spark application correctly writing event logs?**

  - Go to `spark.eventLog.dir` and check whether there are entries in there. You should have an entry per spark application that you ran.
- **Is my History Server running?**

  - There are multiple ways to check this.

    - Type `jps` on the machine on which you're running the History Server. You should see a Java Process called `HistoryServer` running.
    - Visit port 18080 on that machine (if local, go to `localhost:18080`) to see if it's running
- If your applications are writing to the correct location, and your history server is running but you still don't see any application entry on port 18080 from the point above, your history server might not be reading from the correct directory. Verify the value of `spark.history.fs.logDirectory`.

Comment: I already checked all your suggestions. All applications are definitely writing their logs to the correct place, and the History Server is also reading from the correct directory. The history server is even parsing files. It just does not display them.

Comment: Hmmm interesting. So when you visit port `18080` on the machine which is running the History Server using a web browser, do you see a Spark-UI type of web page?

Comment: Yep. I'm seeing this: https://imgur.com/a/LTUwBbn

Comment: Ok, can you show the output of the `ls` command inside of `spark.history.fs.logDirectory`?

Comment: Sure, running `./hdfs dfs -ls /eventLogging` returns

-rw-rw----   1 spark supergroup     147070 2023-01-03 15:23 /eventLogging/application_1672759312184_0001

Comment: [Let's continue this discuss in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250825/room-for-koedlt-and-luke)

Comment: I am seeing this problem too and I am stumped. I can't seem to get my application to write anything to the spark.eventLog.dir and there are no errors. Are the event logs supposed to be written by the driver or the worker? Are there loggers I can turn on to find out what is happening?

Comment: They are supposed to be written by the driver. If you turn on `INFO` level logging, you should get [this](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/87a5442f7ed96b11051d8a9333476d080054e5a0/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/history/EventLogFileWriters.scala#L107) kind of message if your setup is properly done.

Comment: I face same issue too with spark 3.3.2, it just stucks at Parsing eventLog. When I enable Debug or Trace level in log4j2, I can even see that Spark history server can check status and even get size of eventlog. But then nothing happens more. Can anyone help me please

Comment: Hmm @Cobe9696 can you make a separate question post and add some more info about your problem? Like the contents of your logs (that you see the history server can check status and size of the eventlogs) and maybe a screenshot of what you're seeing? You can tag me here with a link to your question post and I'll have a look :)

Comment: @Koedlt here is my question link, sorry if I spam too much: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76224731/spark-history-server-stuck-at-parsing-eventlog-in-s3 , thanks